# asp.net mvc: return url in different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I redirect to another controller?

I have a return url set up like this:

On an `Admin/estates` View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Estates", new {returnUrl = "Admin/Estates"}))
{ %>
      <%: Html.Hidden("EstateId", estate.EstateId) %>
      <button type="submit" onclick="return DoDelete()">Delete</button>
<% } %>
```

Calls to Estates controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(FormCollection collection, string returnUrl)
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Estates"));
    }
```

My problem is that if i send the delete from the admin, it redirects to the non-existent url: `localhost/estates/admin/estates`. How do I redirect properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Estates");
```

and in your form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Estates", 
    new { returnUrl = Url.Action("Admin", "Estates") }))
{ %>
      <%: Html.Hidden("EstateId", estate.EstateId) %>
      <button type="submit" onclick="return DoDelete()">Delete</button>
<% } %>
```

Comment: same problem, `Redirect(returnUrl)` sends me to the same `localhost/estates/admin/estates` url

Comment: `new { returnUrl = Url.Action("Admin", "Estates") }`